# Кого можно позвать?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

При помощи `@` перед именем в комментарии можно позвать:

- Автора вопроса/ответа
- Любого написавшего комментарий к сообщению
- Участника чата в этом чате (всегда ли?)
- Того, кто вносил правку к сообщению

А кого ещё можно позвать? Например, можно ли позвать

- Автора вопроса в комментарии к ответу, который он не комментировал?
- Участника, чья правка была отклонена?
- Участника, проверившего это сообщение в одной из очередей?
- В чате того, кто в него заходил, но ничего не писал?
- В чате, куда были перенесены комментарии, комментатора, который не заходил в чат?
- Того, кто комментировал сообщение, но затем удалил все свои комментарии к нему?
- Другого отвечающего на вопрос в комментарии к вопросу?
- Другого отвечающего на вопрос в комментарии к ответу, который писал не он?

PS: Может ещё какие полезные варианты забыл.

Comment: Бабку, внучку, жучку, кошку, мышку. Но мышка разведет холивар, будьте осторожны. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ответ отрицательный на все вопросы, кроме одного:

> В чате того, кто в него заходил, но ничего не писал

Если участник был в комнате чата в последние два дня, оповещение работает: это не зависит от того, писал или нет.

В отношении комментариев есть ещё две малоизвестные возможности сообщений:

1. В комментариях к вопросу можно оповестить участника, который закрыл или переоткрыл вопрос, используя право решающего голоса: т.е., модератор или участник с золотым знаком метки на вопросе.  Это может быть полезно, если вопрос был помечен как дубликат по ошибке.
2. В комментариях к вопросу можно оповестить участника, объявившего конкурс на вопрос (не имеет значения когда; конкурс мог быть год назад)

В целом, правило в отношении комментариев к сообщению таково: можно позвать любого участника, упомянутого в истории этого сообщения ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/493974/revisions)) за исключением тех, кто его закрыл/переоткрыл используя обычные голоса за закрытие/переоткрытие.

Источник части перечисленного: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: Надо же. Я думал, что позвать можно кого угодно, написав `@` перед псевдонимом

Comment: А если модератор или обладатель золотой метки голосует пятым, этот голос считается решающим?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, считается. Это видно в таблице PostHistory, где в строке Post Closed прописано имя закрывшего участника. Если решающего голоса нет, то им считается Дух - [пример](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/155370/post-history-viewer?PostId=495026). А в [этом случае](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/155370/post-history-viewer?PostId=480292) пятым был модератор, и его имя указано в таблице.  Система уведомлений с этим связана.

Comment: @Sally понял, спасибо.