# Надо синонимизировать метки на тему [таймер]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать метки

- [timer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timer) (204 вопроса) (есть описание)
- [таймер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80) (141 вопрос) (нет описания)

Основная - [таймер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80), т. к. она на русском языке, да и к тому же, описание метки [timer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timer) начинается с `Таймер-это ...`, т. е. они действительно про одно и то же.

Comment: @Зонтик, ну как, у меня получилось следовать вашим [правилам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12973/507426)?

Comment: [Кого можно позвать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2576/)

Comment: Даже добавляю это предложение о синонимизации в положительные примеры =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Добавлено описание в [таймер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80)
- Синонимизированы метки [timer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timer) → [таймер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80)

```
updating post history, 234 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 204 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 198 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'timer': [timer] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 339
tag remapping of [таймер] and [timer] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
2 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```